# JavaScript Runs in Console But Not AppleScript

Tags: javascript, applescript

The following JavaScript runs in the console window and returns the results I was hoping for:

```
var thisAddys = $('.persons .firstChild td').each(function() {
$(this).find('font').each(function() {
    console.log('Data Found: ' + $(this).text());
});
});
```

But when I try to run the JavaScript code with AppleScript I get missing value:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set theScript to "var thisAddys = $('.persons .firstChild td').each(function() {
    $(this).find('font').each(function() {
        console.log('Data Found: ' + $(this).text());
    });
    });"
    set JSResults to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
    activate

end tell
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please double check the formatting of your code

Comment: Have you tried making this code work without JQuery, since it looks like you are probably dealing with a dependency issue.

Comment: I found the JavaScript code on a website that explained the code enough so I could modify it to my needs.  Not sure how to do it without JQuery.

Comment: As @AndreM mentioned: Maybe the site's JQuery context is not available from outside the webpage (AppleScript remoting Safari). Even the first $ returns `missing value`. It looks like this: When executing your code inside the console you have access to libraries imported by the web site.